# Configurable Products not visible on Front end - Magento 1.5

Tags: magento

I have approx 30k Simple SKU with 950 Configurable products. I have used MAGMI to upload the inventory on my website. The inventory is successfully added to my website, I can see my simple products associated with configurable products properly. But the main problem is they wont show on the frontend.

I have done the following things

1. Checked the status if the item is in stock or not
2. Simple products have inventory in them

The main surprise is when I add the configurable product manually then it shows in the frontend. I am not sure what is the reason behind it. can someone help?

Answer (score 7):

To make a configurable product visible in the front end you should only have to do the following.

- On the inventory tab, mark availability as 'In Stock'.
- Ensure there is a simple product associated.
- Ensure the simple product has availability marked as 'In Stock'.
- Ensure the simple product has qty set above the out of stock quantity
  threshold.
- Ensure both the simple product and configurable product is associated to the correct website.
- On the General tab of the configurable make sure Visibility is set to
  something other than not visible individually.
- Re-index (System > Index Management > Select All > Submit.

Comment: Thanks for your answer Cags. Points from 1 - 5 have been already done. The Re-index doesn't work properly from admin as it hangs. I had to do it from the SSH but still the products are not visible.

Comment: Are the configurables accessible by their URL?

Comment: Yes Cags. I just had to do the reindexing through SSH and everything works fine now.

Comment: same for me, everything is ok, only reindexing remaining

Comment: I'd like to add a bullet. - Ensure both the simple product and configurable product is associated to the correct website.

Comment: Can you associate two products together if they aren't associated to the same site? I'm not sure you can, but added anyway. :)

Answer (score 0):

This usually happens with custom product importing when a key attribute is missed. To prove this, try the following things:

- Select a configurable product via the Magento Admin and save it. Then go to one of it's simple products and save that too.
- Manually add the configurable product (you have already done this)

If either - or both - of these fix the issue, you know that the import has not worked correctly

Comment: Hello fish,I sorted out the problem. It was an indexing issue and nothing else. I had to reindex through SHELL and everything seems good now.

Answer (score 0):

Re-index (System > Index Management > Select All > Submit.

Problem Solved..